# Each product have many uom

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

How to design database table?
Each product has many product  unit of measure.
For example, product puff 150 pcs =1 carton and 8pcs =1 carton. Two measurement for each product

Comment: For UOM (from your context) i got units of measure. In future questions I suggest you not to use acronyms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a 'type of container' table where each product ID has 1 row for each type of container: Ex:

```
ITEM: (ID,NAME),  
PACKS: (PRODUCT_ID, NUMBER_OF_PIECES_PER_PACK, PRICE_PER_PACK)
```

So you'll have a table with:

```
PRODUCTS:
 ID, Name  
 1, MILK  
 2, YEAST
```

And another with:

```
PACKS:
PR_ID,  #_of_peieces, price_per_container  
 1,     12,           12€  
 1,     1,            1,2€  
 2,     4,            0,6€
```

In this case your milk has 'per carton' price of 1,2€ and per 'box' price of 12€/dozen while YEAST is sold in 6-pieces boxes for 60c/6pieces